# Hard time passing two dimensional arrays to functions

Tags: c

so I'm working on this code,in which I'm trying to pass a two dimensional array to a function ,like so:

function signature : void f(array[4][4],int n);

```
int array [4][4];
f(&array[0][0],16)
for (int i=0;i<n;i++) // I'm working by c99 standard.
{
 hist[ *(&array[0][0] +i) ] ++ ;  // I know the max value in array[4][4] , and hist is initialized accordingly.
}
}
```

I just keep getting all kinds of errors regarding incompatible types , for example , I get "expected (*)[4] but type is of int *
help ? :)

Comment: What happens if you just do `f(array,16)`?

Answer (score 0):

`&array[0][0]` is an int pointer.

A pointer can't be converted to a two-dimensional array. For this reason, you need to pass it like `f(array, 16)`. Basically you're passing an `int*` and that is incompatible with an `int[][4]`.

It's worth pointing out that this is valid for one dimensional arrays (though it's unnecessary and potentially confusing):

```
void g(int x[]) {}
int arr[4];
g(arr); //valid of course
g(&arr[0]); //also valid
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12813676/567864) explains why it's different with multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: is this syntax valid ?
`f (array,n)
{
for (int i=0;i<n;i++) // assuming that array is nxn.
{
for(int j=o;j<n;j++)
{
*(*(array+i)+j) = somthing; // am I accessing the element in the i'th line , j'th column ?`

Comment: @user1965208 `f (array,n)` is an invalid function signature. Also, if array is a 2d array, you should just use `array[i][j]`. The `*(*(array+i)+j)` is indeed correct--at least syntactically--though.

Comment: actually I've already declared the function's signature in the first comment, and secondly , in hindsight I realized that you're correct, it may have been easier to use brackets , but this mistake has benefited me because I've learned so much about multi-dimensional arrays in the past hour or so.
Anyway , thank you for your replies :)