# How to correctly declare a const string array?

Tags: c

This is a silly question, but I can't seem to get it right. I came across another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29205864/how-to-declare-a-constant-2d-string-array-in-c), but the answer given doesn't properly address the warnings in my specific use case.

I'm trying to declare an array of constant strings to pass as `argv` in [`posix_spawn`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/posix_spawn.html) function, but GCC complains about `const` being discarded. See a sample code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Similar signature as posix_spawn() shown for brevity. */
static void show(char *const argv[])
{
    unsigned i = 0;

    while(argv[i] != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i++]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    const char exe[] = "/usr/bin/some/exe";

    char *const argv[] = {
        exe,
        "-a",
        "-b",
        NULL
    };

    show(argv);

    return 0;
}
```

And compile it as:

```
gcc -std=c89 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wwrite-strings test.c -o test 
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:17:9: warning: initializer element is not computable at load time [-Wpedantic]
         exe,
         ^
test.c:17:9: warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
test.c:18:9: warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
         "-a",
         ^
test.c:19:9: warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
         "-b",
         ^
```

Since, `exe` is itself a constant string like `"-a"` and `"-b"`, I thought it's correct. But GCC seems to disagree. Removing `exe` from the array and removing `-Wwrite-strings` compiles without warnings. Maybe I am missing something too basic.

How does one declare a const array of strings?

Comment: "I came across another question"  - the accepted answer to that question is correct (and there are no "warnings"), however that question does not involve `const` in any way so it is not clear why you have linked it

Comment: The op was trying to put literal constant strings inside a non-const array. GCC normally warns. And in my case due to `-Werror`, it fails with errors instead.

Comment: String literals are not `const` in C.  The code was correct. You see warnings because you use the switch `-Wwrite-strings` which intentionally produces warnings for correct code.

Comment: I thought string literals are stored in read-only section irrespective of warning switches, unless `-fwritable-strings` is also used. But you're right, the standard doesn't specify such a behaviour though. Corrected my question's wording. Thanks.

Comment: They could be stored in read-only area, but either way there is no `const` qualifier.  It is just undefined behaviour with no diagnostic to write them, in Standard C. The `-Wwrite-strings` attempts to catch write attempts, but also gives false positives when you need to call an API that isn't const-correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function in question, `posix_spawn`, expects a pointer to (the first element of) an array of pointer to non-const `char`. Despite this, the function does not modify the character strings.

For historical reasons this situation of poor const-correctness in C APIs is not uncommon.

You can pass string literals to it without any warning in Standard C, because string literals have type: array of non-const char.  (Modifying them is undefined behaviour with no diagnostic required).

If you use the `-Wwrite-strings` flag to try and get warnings about potential UB then it will give you these false positives for the cases where you interact with a non-const-correct API.

---

The intended way to consume the API in C89 would be to use:

```
char exe[] = "/usr/bin/some/exe";

char * argv[] = {
    NULL,
    "-a",
    "-b",
    NULL
};

argv[0] = exe;
show(argv);
```

Note that in C89 it is not possible to have your array be `const` and also be initialized with the local variable `exe`. This is because C89 requires all initializers in a braced list to be *constant expressions*, the definition of which excludes the address of a local variable.

If you want to use `-Wwrite-strings` then you could suppress the warning by using `(char *)"-a"` instead of `"-a"` and so on.

---

It was suggested in comments to use `const char *` for the string type and then use a cast, like so:

```
const char exe[] = "/usr/bin/some/exe";

const char * argv[] = {
    NULL,
    "-a",
    "-b",
    NULL
};
argv[0] = exe;
show((char **)argv);
```

However this probably violates the *strict aliasing rule*.  Even though the rule allows a `const T` to be aliased as a `T`, this rule does not "recurse" ; it is probably not allowed to alias `const char *` as `char *` , although the rule's wording is not 100% clear.  [See this question for further discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45124063/is-it-okay-for-int-and-const-int-to-alias).

If you wanted to offer a wrapper that accepts `const char **` and calls `posix_spawn` , and not violate the C Standard, then you would actually have to make a copy of the pointer list into an array of `char *`.  (But you do not have to actually copy the string content)

Comment: I can't modify the signature of `posix_spawn` so it accepts `const char *const []`, no? Also, your answer works for this instance though. I have changed my code to wrap `posix_spawn` so it works like how you've shown in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration `char *const argv[]` makes `argv` an array of constant pointers to *mutable* `char`s. Once you create the array, you cannot change where the pointers point (you can't say `argv[0] = "/bin/some_other_program"`), but you can change the characters themselves (so `argv[1][1] = 'b'`, to make it so you pass `-b` instead).

However, the pointers you are assigning as elements of `argv` are pointers to constant `char`s. It's undefined behavior to actually do any of those assignments even if the type of `argv` will let you, hence the warning. Since you can't change the type of the function, you need to get rid of the `const`ness somehow. Options are to use `strdup`, to put the strings into `char[]` variables (which implicitly also copies them), or to cast away the `const` at this level (which is UB if the program actually modifies the values but should be safe if it does not). [Here](https://godbolt.org/g/CgcETw) are examples using the latter two methods.

Comment: Changing it like your suggestion doesn't match with posix_spawn() function signature. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/posix_spawn.html. Does this mean, I have to `strdup()` every string inside `argv`?

Comment: No, if you create arrays of pointers to non-`const` `char`s (for example, remove the `const` from `exe`), it should work. But I am somewhat surprised; I would not expect `posix_spawn` to want to actually change the values passed in so I don't know why it wants them mutable. I'm not certain, but I also think as long as it doesn't *actually* change anything it is perfectly defined to cast away the `const`ness of the pointers.

Comment: once the pointers get deep, const becomes very tricky and hard to understand: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055655/double-pointer-const-correctness-warnings-in-c

Comment: @EvanBenn Yeah, definitely. I suppose that could change details of why the API is designed with non-`const` `char`s, but I don't think it changes my answer.

Comment: @EvanBenn Makes sense. But how do I avoid this specific case here? Use `pragama`?

Comment: @UnmannedPlayer Daniel H's answer is good, you could be strdup'ing or similar, IF you want to heed the -Wwrite-strings warning. Presumably posix_spawn will not modify the strings, so it is reasonably safe to 'discard the const qualifier'. The common librarys are full of such things eg char* index(const char* input...). Const correctness is a battle that cannot be won in C.

Comment: It is not required to copy the actual content of the strings ;  you can safely cast `const char *` to `char *` and then read the const strings through that pointer.

Comment: @M.M Yep, and I do say that. On some level I don't like that solution because my instincts were formed in C++ where the safe conversions are actually possible and people design APIs accordingly (or those who don't shouldn't be trusted to not actually modify the strings), but it's probably what I'd go with too.