# why specify column size when pass 2d array into function

Tags: c, arrays

Many people say compiler would not know the size information if no column size is provided. But How compiler knows the row size? And why column size can't be interpreted?

Comment: What's the language you are talking about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we need to specify the column size when passing a 2D array as a parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813494/why-do-we-need-to-specify-the-column-size-when-passing-a-2d-array-as-a-parameter)

Comment: I am talking about c ,

Comment: Yeah, I saw that  post  before . But that lost me .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While passing an array as an argument to a function, compiler implicitly converts the array reference to the pointer. This can be clearly seen in the case of one dimensional array, like

```
    int method(int *a)
    int method(int a[])
```

Both these lines are equivalent here (although pointer and array reference are different) because whenever an array appears in an expression, the compiler implicitly generates a pointer to the array's first element, just as if the programmer had written &a[0]. However this rule is not recursive i.e. passing a 2d array is treated as pointer to an array, not a pointer to a pointer.

```
    int method(int b[3][5]);
```

is converted to

```
    int method(int (*b)[5]);
```

And since the called function doesn't allocate space for the array so size of row is not important, however size  of column is still important to provide the size of array. For further reference you can visit [here](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html).

Comment: Hi,Rajeev. Thanks for you  good post and reference. That really gave something new to me. However, I  am still unclear with one sentence:"Since the called function does not allocate space for the array, it does not need to know the overall size, so the number of rows, NROWS, can be omitted. The width of the array is still important"

Comment: Just remember a 2d array is implicitly array of pointers, and as you know for every array size must be mentioned, and here the size is column size .@user3529352