# How does this code initialize the 2D array?

Tags: c++

I found this piece of code on internet. How does this initialize the array?

```
char words[][MAXLENGTH] =
{
    "india",
    "pakistan",
    "nepal",
    "malaysia",
    "philippines",
    "australia",
    "iran",
    "ethiopia",
    "oman",
    "indonesia"
};
```

Comment: What do you mean *how*?

Comment: What is it exactly you don't understand? There's quite a bit of ground to cover here. You may be better off consulting a decent beginner book instead of asking on SO.

Comment: if you are curious about why we need to specify column size - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813494/why-do-we-need-to-specify-the-column-size-when-passing-a-2d-array-as-a-parameter

Comment: if you want to know how to create array of strings - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-strings-c-3-different-ways-create/

Comment: i wanted to ask that what will exist at words[0][3], and also if this is a good way of initializing a 2-D character array?

Comment: `i` will exist at `words[0][3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given `array` is an array of `strings`. Each index of `words` is a string.

e.g:

`words[0] = "india"`
`words[1] = "pakistan"`
and so on.

You can use `words[0][j]` to refer to the characters present in `india`, `words[1][j]` for referring to characters of `pakistan`.

Maybe the following code will help you visualize the array:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int MAXLENGTH = 10;
    char words[][MAXLENGTH] =
    {
        "india",
        "pakistan",
        "nepal",
        "malaysia",
        "philippines",
        "australia",
        "iran",
        "ethiopia",
        "oman",
        "indonesia"
    };

    for(int i=0;i<MAXLENGTH;i++)
    {
        std::string s = words[i];
        for(int j=0;j<s.size();j++)
        {
            std::cout << words[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh yeah! thanks! this helped me figure it out

Comment: accept it if it helped you

Comment: The tick mark, I guess, lets me accept an answer.. Right??

Comment: Yeah... Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`char words[][MAXLENGTH]` 
Initialises a 2D array of characters. Basically defines an array of elements and each element in the array is an array of characters e.g. `"india"`

`MAXLENGTH`
Defines the maximum length of each word in the words array.

`char singleWord[] = {"india"}` -> an array of characters, meaning by calling `singleWord[0]` the character `i` would be returned.

By calling `words[2]` the character array `"nepal"` would be returned.

I'm not sure exactly what kind of answer you were looking for, but if you have any questions let me know.