# error: no matching function for call to 'displayScreenXY' in 2D Table

Tags: c++

I'm learning c++, I'm trying to display simple table with X Y coordinates in each case.
But when I build it I get this error :
*error: no matching function for call to 'displayScreenXY'*

I tried to replace

```
void displayScreenXY(int **tab, int x, int y);
```

by

```
void displayScreenXY(int tab[][], int x, int y);
```

but I get this error :
*error: array has incomplete element type 'int []'
void displayScreenXY(int tab[][], int x, int y);*

What I am missing ?
Thanks for your help.

Zoltan

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define xDiv 8
#define yDiv 6


void displayScreenXY(int **tab, int x, int y);

int main(){
    int screenXY[yDiv][xDiv] = {0};

    displayScreenXY(screenXY, xDiv, yDiv);

    return 0;
}

void displayScreenXY(int **tab, int x, int y){
    for (int j = 0; j < y; ++j){
        for (int k = 0; k < x; ++k){
            std::cout << j << k << " ";
        }
        std::cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: A multidimensional array is not a  pointer to pointer array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813494/why-do-we-need-to-specify-the-column-size-when-passing-a-2d-array-as-a-parameter

Comment: actually there are two issues here. Why you get an error for `int tab[][]` is explained in the q&a i linked above, but I realized it isnt a good duplicate for your question.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 it's it helps me, but still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion of a pointer to an array only applies to the outermost dimension of a multidimensional array.  So a `int [yDiv][xDiv]` cannot be converted to a `int **`.

If you change the signature to:

```
void displayScreenXY(int tab[yDiv][xDiv], int x, int y);
```

It will work as expected.

Comment: so I did the correction and now I get : _error: no matching function for call to 'displayScreenXY'_