# How to pass 2-d static array in a function using pointers (C)

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, static

I'm trying to create a static 2-d array via passing in to the function, where I specify `n` number of records and then read it. Need to use pointers.

```
#define NMAX 100
void CreateStatic(int* matrix, int* n);

int main() {
    // int num;
    int matrix[NMAX][NMAX], n;
    CreateStatic(*matrix, &n);
}

void CreateStatic(int* matrix, int* n) {
    scanf("%d", n)
    for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < *n; j++) {
            scanf("%d", a);
        }
    }
}
```

What should I write instead of `a` to make it work?

Do I pass a correct type into the function? (*matrix, int * matrix)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass 2D array (matrix) in a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911400/how-to-pass-2d-array-matrix-in-a-function-in-c)

Comment: Why do you use `*matrix` when calling `CreateStatic`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you are looking for is a Variable Length Array VLA.
The function `vla` allocates the array on the stack so it's size is limited. The array is initialized to zero and passed to `fillvla`.
For simplicity, `fillvla` assigns a value to each element. `value` is declared `static` so on subsequent calls for this example the value increases.
`vla` then prints the contents of the array and returns. Upon return, `matrix` no longer exists so the next iteration in `main` can call `vla` with a different dimension.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void vla( int dim);
void fillvla( int dim, int matrix[][dim]);

int main() {
    // int num;
    for (int dim = 2; dim < 6; dim++) {
        vla( dim);
    }
}

void vla( int dim) {
    int matrix[dim][dim];//vla valid in this function
    for (int row = 0; row < dim; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < dim; col++) {
            matrix[row][col] = 0;
        }
    }
    fillvla ( dim, matrix);//vla can be passed to a function
    for (int row = 0; row < dim; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < dim; col++) {
            printf ( "%2d ", matrix[row][col]);
        }
        printf ( "\n");
    }
    printf ( "\n");
}

void fillvla( int dim, int matrix[][dim]) {
    static int value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = value++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `CreateStatic` accepts a pointer to integer as parameter, not a bidimensional array. In case you wanted to dynamically allocate the bidimensional array **inside** the function, you would have to declare it as `int **matrix;` and pass it to the function like this `CreateStatic(matrix, &n);`, then call `malloc` properly inside the function. If you, instead, wanted to declare it with a fixed number of columns and rows, you need to specify how many cols it has when you're calling the function like this `CreateStatic(matrix[][NMAX], &n);`, since the function needs to know at least the number of columns of it.

Comment: ``` matrix[][NMAX]; ``` 
Could I ask you how does this construction work as a function parameter?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813494/why-do-we-need-to-specify-the-column-size-when-passing-a-2d-array-as-a-parameter) you go.

Answer (score 0):

For starters within the function `CreateStatic` you are using undeclared variable `a`.

```
 scanf("%d", a);
```

This call

```
scanf("%d", n);
```

should be moved from the function in main. That is the function should be called with already specified number of rows in the matrix.

The array `matrix` used as an argument of a function call is converted to a pointer to the first element (row) of the array and has the type `int ( * )[NMAX]`.

So the function `CreateStatic` will look the following way

```
void CreateStatic( int ( *matrix )[NMAX], size_t n ) 
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < NMAX; j++ ) 
        {
            scanf( "%d", &matrix[i][j] );
        }
    }
}
```

In this function definition it is supposed that the n specifies only the number of rows. If you want that `n` specified the number of rows and the number of columns simultaneously then you can change the inner loop the following way

```
void CreateStatic( int ( *matrix )[NMAX], size_t n ) 
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ ) 
        {
            scanf( "%d", &matrix[i][j] );
        }
    }
}
```

And in main the function can be called like

```
int matrix[NMAX][NMAX];
size_t n;

if ( scanf( "%zu", &n ) != 1 || NMAX < n ) n =  NMAX;

CreateStatic( matrix, n );
```

Comment: Should `j < NMAX` be `j < n`?

Comment: @IanAbbott I suppose that n specifiers the number of rows in the array.  The number of columns is fixed.

Comment: But the original code was trying to input a square matrix. Only the top left corner of the 2D array is used.